# Execute unix executables (python) in Electron

Tags: python, node.js, electron, node-modules

I have the following file structure:

```
--backend/
---script (unix executable)
--src/
---script_launcher.js
---main.js
--all other necessary files
```

`script` is a unix executable which I built from python script using `pyinstaller`. `script_launcher.js` should start the unix executable `script`, pass arguments through standard input to it and listen to: any standard output/any errors/when the script is finished executing. Before unix executable I had a `.py` file in its place which I would call using [python-shell npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) from `script_launcher.js`. I know I should use `child-processes` but then:

- `spawn` seems to only work on python scripts and not on unix executables (doesn't allow me to execute `script`)

`const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
 const pythonProcess = spawn("path/to/script", arg1, arg2);`

- `exec` or `execFile` seems to not allow me read info that I described above in the way that `python-shell` lets me read info.

What would be the best approach to this problem to call unix executables? Also, when calling them, should I use path as `/path/to/script` or `/path/to/script.exec`? I don't really understand whether `script` has a filename extension or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the executable locations and the command line arguments

```
const unixProcess = spawn('path/to/executable',[arg1, arg2, arg3, ...]);
```

Example

```
const unixProcess = spawn('/usr/bin/whoami',[arg1, arg2, arg3, ...]);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input, but as the question states: I need to execute unix executable, not python executable. I already can execute .py files. Sorry, I just found a typo in my post - it should have been written unix executable there.

Comment: The path must be absolute if you do it like this. Thanks.